# how to customize mouse events for each link (how to write a generic fn)

Tags: jquery

I have couple of links in a page for which I need to run the following jquery code. For example, the following code is written for one link (id=ewom) and within this code I call a js fn (called, DisplayAlert) with the parameter "ewom".  I can duplicate this function and replace the ewom keyword accordingly.  However, I prefer to write a generic code that can function appropriately for different links.  How can I do that?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //$('#submit').click(function () {
    //document.getElementById("term").innerHTML = "erkan";
    //});
    var permanotice, tooltip, _alert;
    $('#ewom').live('mouseover mouseout', function (event) {
        if (event.type == 'mouseover') {

            DisplayAlert('ewom');

            $(function () {
                //$.pnotify.defaults.styling = "bootstrap3";            
                // This notice is used as a tooltip.
                var make_tooltip = function () {
                    tooltip = $.pnotify({
                        title: $("#term").text(),
                        text: $("#definition").text(),
                        hide: false,
                        closer: false,
                        sticker: false,
                        history: false,
                        animate_speed: 100,
                        opacity: 1,
                        icon: "ui-icon ui-icon-comment",
                        // Setting stack to false causes PNotify to ignore this notice when positioning.
                        stack: false,
                        after_init: function (pnotify) {
                            // Remove the notice if the user mouses over it.

                            pnotify.mouseout(function () {
                                pnotify.pnotify_remove();
                            });
                        },
                        before_open: function (pnotify) {
                            // This prevents the notice from displaying when it's created.
                            pnotify.pnotify({
                                before_open: null
                            });

                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
                // I put it in a function so I could show the source easily.
                make_tooltip();
            });

            tooltip.pnotify_display();
        } else {
            // do something on mouseout
            tooltip.pnotify_remove();
        }
    });

    $('#ewom').mousemove(function (event) {
        tooltip.css({
            'top': event.clientY + 12,
            'left': event.clientX + 12
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: If the function needs to fire when a user clicks different links, those links need to be selected somehow and bound to the click event. If the function should only be run when the user clicks specific links, maybe a common class added to each link would be a better selector, i.e. `$('.trigger')`?

Comment: please show `DisplayAlert` function

Comment: @Sionnach733 Here is the display function (called in a separate js file): `code` function DisplayAlert(t) {
 
 getTerm = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(t);
 term = (getTerm[0].getElementsByTagName("term")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
 definition = (getTerm[0].getElementsByTagName("definition")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
 document.getElementById("AlertBox").style.display='none'; 
 document.getElementById("term").innerHTML = term;
 document.getElementById("definition").innerHTML = definition;
} `code`

Comment: @Dpeif, so you mean I should add this attribute to those links class='trigger' right? Then, can I retrieve the id of the link clicked?  I am asking this because I can transfer the parameter of the DisplayAlert function this way.

Comment: @Dpeif, it worked, I retrieved the object id with this code event.target.id and add the class attribute.  Thanks!

Comment: @erkaner no problem, i was actually saying that if the link IDs are all unique (as they should be), binding the function to the ID is what's making things hard. Binding it to a class that's common to all the links might make things simpler, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gjRC/) with a basic demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution with the contribution of @Dpeif

a sample link:

```
 <a href="#" name="ewom" id="ewom" class="triger">EWOM</a>
```

and the generic code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {     

                var permanotice, tooltip, _alert;
                $('.triger').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
                    if (event.type == 'mouseover') {                    

                        DisplayAlert(event.target.id);

                        $(function(){                   
                            //$.pnotify.defaults.styling = "bootstrap3";            
                            // This notice is used as a tooltip.
                            var make_tooltip = function(){
                                tooltip = $.pnotify({
                                    title: $("#term").text(),
                                    text: $("#definition").text(),
                                    hide: false,
                                    closer: false,
                                    sticker: false,
                                    history: false,
                                    animate_speed: 100,
                                    opacity: 1,
                                    width:"460px",
                                    icon: "ui-icon ui-icon-comment",
                                    // Setting stack to false causes PNotify to ignore this notice when positioning.
                                    stack: false,
                                    after_init: function(pnotify){
                                        // Remove the notice if the user mouses over it.

                                        pnotify.mouseout(function(){
                                            pnotify.pnotify_remove();
                                        });
                                    },
                                    before_open: function(pnotify){
                                        // This prevents the notice from displaying when it's created.
                                        pnotify.pnotify({
                                            before_open: null
                                        });

                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            // I put it in a function so I could show the source easily.
                            make_tooltip();         
                        }); 

                        tooltip.pnotify_display();
                    }
                    else {
                        // do something on mouseout
                        tooltip.pnotify_remove();
                    }
                });

                $('.triger').mousemove(function( event ){
                    tooltip.css({'top': event.clientY+12, 'left': event.clientX+12});
                });         
            });         

        </script>
```